# How do you connect MySQL to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed this post, http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion.

I have been learning Ruby and Rails for a month, so I am quite familiar with Ruby. I also know some parts of Rails due to the understandings acquired by following several tutorials.

However, I continuously fail to `gem install mysql` or `gem install mysql2` prior to `rails new photos -d mysql`.

I already successfully finished `brew install mysql` and checked `mysql -u root`.

```
seodongju@Seoui-MacBook-Pro ~/Desktop/Projects$ sudo gem install mysql2 
Password: 
Building native extensions. This could take a while... 
ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes checking for rb_intern3()... yes checking for mysql.h... no

checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
mysql.h is missing. please check your installation of mysql and try again.
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options: --with-opt-dir --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby --with-mysql-config --without-mysql-config

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection. Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: `Check the mkmf.log file for more details` - post the contents of that file in your question, it should be located in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2xxxx/ext/mysql2/`

Comment: Short answer, you need the native mysql libraries for the ruby gem to lin to. Since you are using Mac OS so if you have homebrew installed just run `brew install mysql`. If not, head over to Mysql site and download the mysql pkg.

Comment: Like I said, I already did brew install mysql.

Comment: @Bert // There is nothing in 'gems' folder.

Comment: Have you tried running your rails app? `rails server` or `rails s` in the terminal. Post if you get an error in your terminal.

Answer (score -2):

You should install MySQL on your machine first

Take it from here

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer

After installing it install the Gem